# WebGL: Loading same data into two attributes

Tags: javascript, webgl

I was going through [this website](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html) when I came across the following code in the snippet.

I got lost in the code where `positionBuffer` was created, and `gl.ARRAY_BUFFER` was bound to it. It seems that no data was loaded onto the newly created buffer, but instead, the buffer was bound to the attribute `a_postion`. Later on, a new buffer `texCoordBuffer` was created and some data was written onto it. In the results, it seems like this same data had been loaded by webGL into the `a_position` attribute as well. My doubt is, how did this happen? When a new buffer was created and the buffer pointer `gl.ARRAY_BUFFER` was pointed to the new array, how did the `positionBuffer` get the same data?

```js
// WebGL2 - 2D image 3x3 convolution
// from https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-2d-image-3x3-convolution.html


"use strict";

var vertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es

// an attribute is an input (in) to a vertex shader.
// It will receive data from a buffer
in vec2 a_position;
in vec2 a_texCoord;

// Used to pass in the resolution of the canvas
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

// Used to pass the texture coordinates to the fragment shader
out vec2 v_texCoord;

// all shaders have a main function
void main() {

  // convert the position from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
  vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

  // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
  vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

  // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
  vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

  gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);

  // pass the texCoord to the fragment shader
  // The GPU will interpolate this value between points.
  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
`;

var fragmentShaderSource = `#version 300 es

// fragment shaders don't have a default precision so we need
// to pick one. highp is a good default. It means "high precision"
precision highp float;

// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;

// the convolution kernal data
uniform float u_kernel[9];
uniform float u_kernelWeight;

// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
in vec2 v_texCoord;

// we need to declare an output for the fragment shader
out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  vec2 onePixel = vec2(1) / vec2(textureSize(u_image, 0));

  vec4 colorSum =
      texture(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1, -1)) * u_kernel[0] +
      texture(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0, -1)) * u_kernel[1] +
      texture(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1, -1)) * u_kernel[2] +
      texture(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1,  0)) * u_kernel[3] +
      texture(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0,  0)) * u_kernel[4] +
      texture(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1,  0)) * u_kernel[5] +
      texture(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1,  1)) * u_kernel[6] +
      texture(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0,  1)) * u_kernel[7] +
      texture(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1,  1)) * u_kernel[8] ;
  outColor = vec4((colorSum / u_kernelWeight).rgb, 1);
}
`;

var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/leaves.jpg";  // MUST BE SAME DOMAIN!!!
image.onload = function() {
  render(image);
};

function render(image) {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromSources(gl,
      [vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var texCoordAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");

  // lookup uniforms
  var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
  var imageLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_image");
  var kernelLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_kernel[0]");
  var kernelWeightLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_kernelWeight");

  // Create a vertex array object (attribute state)
  var vao = gl.createVertexArray();

  // and make it the one we're currently working with
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  // Create a buffer and put a single pixel space rectangle in
  // it (2 triangles)
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Turn on the attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Tell the attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
  var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
  var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
  var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
  var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      positionAttributeLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Turn on the attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttributeLocation);

  // Tell the attribute how to get data out of texCoordBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
  var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
  var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
  var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
  var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      texCoordAttributeLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  // Create a texture.
  var texture = gl.createTexture();

  // make unit 0 the active texture uint
  // (ie, the unit all other texture commands will affect
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 0);

  // Bind it to texture unit 0's 2D bind point
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Set the parameters so we don't need mips and so we're not filtering
  // and we don't repeat at the edges.
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  // Upload the image into the texture.
  var mipLevel = 0;               // the largest mip
  var internalFormat = gl.RGBA;   // format we want in the texture
  var srcFormat = gl.RGBA;        // format of data we are supplying
  var srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE; // type of data we are supplying
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,
                mipLevel,
                internalFormat,
                srcFormat,
                srcType,
                image);

  // Bind the position buffer so gl.bufferData that will be called
  // in setRectangle puts data in the position buffer
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Set a rectangle the same size as the image.
  setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

  // Define several convolution kernels
  var kernels = {
    normal: [
      0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 0,
    ],
    gaussianBlur: [
      0.045, 0.122, 0.045,
      0.122, 0.332, 0.122,
      0.045, 0.122, 0.045,
    ],
    gaussianBlur2: [
      1, 2, 1,
      2, 4, 2,
      1, 2, 1,
    ],
    gaussianBlur3: [
      0, 1, 0,
      1, 1, 1,
      0, 1, 0,
    ],
    unsharpen: [
      -1, -1, -1,
      -1,  9, -1,
      -1, -1, -1,
    ],
    sharpness: [
       0, -1,  0,
      -1,  5, -1,
       0, -1,  0,
    ],
    sharpen: [
       -1, -1, -1,
       -1, 16, -1,
       -1, -1, -1,
    ],
    edgeDetect: [
       -0.125, -0.125, -0.125,
       -0.125,  1,     -0.125,
       -0.125, -0.125, -0.125,
    ],
    edgeDetect2: [
       -1, -1, -1,
       -1,  8, -1,
       -1, -1, -1,
    ],
    edgeDetect3: [
       -5, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 5,
    ],
    edgeDetect4: [
       -1, -1, -1,
        0,  0,  0,
        1,  1,  1,
    ],
    edgeDetect5: [
       -1, -1, -1,
        2,  2,  2,
       -1, -1, -1,
    ],
    edgeDetect6: [
       -5, -5, -5,
       -5, 39, -5,
       -5, -5, -5,
    ],
    sobelHorizontal: [
        1,  2,  1,
        0,  0,  0,
       -1, -2, -1,
    ],
    sobelVertical: [
        1,  0, -1,
        2,  0, -2,
        1,  0, -1,
    ],
    previtHorizontal: [
        1,  1,  1,
        0,  0,  0,
       -1, -1, -1,
    ],
    previtVertical: [
        1,  0, -1,
        1,  0, -1,
        1,  0, -1,
    ],
    boxBlur: [
        0.111, 0.111, 0.111,
        0.111, 0.111, 0.111,
        0.111, 0.111, 0.111,
    ],
    triangleBlur: [
        0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625,
        0.125,  0.25,  0.125,
        0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625,
    ],
    emboss: [
       -2, -1,  0,
       -1,  1,  1,
        0,  1,  2,
    ],
  };
  var initialSelection = 'edgeDetect2';

  // Setup UI to pick kernels.
  var ui = document.querySelector("#ui");
  var select = document.createElement("select");
  for (var name in kernels) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = name;
    if (name === initialSelection) {
      option.selected = true;
    }
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
  select.onchange = function() {
    drawWithKernel(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
  };
  ui.appendChild(select);

  drawWithKernel(initialSelection);

  function computeKernelWeight(kernel) {
    var weight = kernel.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        return prev + curr;
    });
    return weight <= 0 ? 1 : weight;
  }

  function drawWithKernel(name) {
    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // Clear the canvas
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Bind the attribute/buffer set we want.
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

    // Pass in the canvas resolution so we can convert from
    // pixels to clipspace in the shader
    gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // Tell the shader to get the texture from texture unit 0
    gl.uniform1i(imageLocation, 0);

    // set the kernel and it's weight
    gl.uniform1fv(kernelLocation, kernels[name]);
    gl.uniform1f(kernelWeightLocation, computeKernelWeight(kernels[name]));

    // Draw the rectangle.
    var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
    var offset = 0;
    var count = 6;
    gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
  }
}

function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  var x1 = x;
  var x2 = x + width;
  var y1 = y;
  var y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     x1, y1,
     x2, y1,
     x1, y2,
     x1, y2,
     x2, y1,
     x2, y2,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

```css
@import url("https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css");
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="uiContainer">
  <div id="ui"></div>
</div>
<!--
for most samples webgl-utils only provides shader compiling/linking and
canvas resizing because why clutter the examples with code that's the same in every sample.
See https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html
and https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html
for webgl-utils, m3, m4, and webgl-lessons-ui.
-->
<script src="https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given I spent more time, I see that `a_position` is an attribute that takes the coordinates of the screen, but `a_texCoord` takes clipspace coordinates of the texture.

However, down in the code (#181),

```js
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
```

the buffer pointer is attached to the `positionBuffer` and then the `setRectangle()` function attaches data to the attribute `a_position`.

To add more to the answer, the line (#115),

```js
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
```

, is put at the top while defining and binding the vertex array object `vao` is because the `gl.vertexAttribPointer()` function needs a bound buffer pointer so that the current `ARRAY_BUFFER` can be attached to the attribute that it is working on.